# Does Firebase sdk batch requests?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does Firebase has some kind of batching for retrieve requests?

For instance, in [this api](https://github.com/HackerNews/API#new-and-top-stories)  top stories request returns up to 500 ids, which means that in order to display them all in a list I need to call `addListenerForSingleEvent" 500 times.

Comment: to get your question right, you want to retrieve only a few of the ids? like say the first 100 or something?

Comment: Let's say first 100 or maybe all 500. What I'm worried about is does it mean I'll be creating respectively 100 and 500 requests to firebase server

Comment: looking at the api, that seems to be the case, so yes. for each id you receive, you'll have to retrieve the data individually.

Comment: Creating many requests to the Firebase database is typically not a big performance problem, because the client pipelines all those requests over a single web socket connection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786